# Makeindex lists "\emph{F} distribution" at the beginning of the index, not alphabetically

Tags: indexing

I want to list "F distribution" alphabetically in my index, but I want F to be italicized.  Whether I use `\emph`, `\it`, `\textit`, or even `$ $`, the entry appears in the unalphabetized list at the beginning of the index (along with other non-alpha symbols).  How can I make this entry appear in the index along with other words beginning with F?

Comment: You ought not be using `\it` it is a few decades obsolete and ought not be used with LaTeX 2e i.e. anything later than the 1980s.

Answer (score 2):

`texdoc makeindex` page 4:

```
\index{alpha@$\alpha$}
```